# How do I make Ember Template Errors Verbose?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Currently, if you have an error in your handlebars/HTMLBars, there is a silent failure and instead of outputting html you get `<!---->`.

Is there a way to get an error message in the console or something to tell me what is wrong?

An example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fumacemero/edit?html,js,output (I know what the error is, I want to figure out how to get an error message from Ember/HTMLBars)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-template-lint

Comment: This wont tell you if the template failed to render because of an invalid property though.